# Vscode autocompletion shows if only space bar pressed

Tags: dart, flutter, visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode for my flutter application. but, autocompletion only shows up when I pressed space bar first. I'm new to vscode configuration, could you help me ?

Comment: Could you please share your configuration file with us?

Comment: @TobiasMarschall hi, sure. https://gist.github.com/dopefaceee/b797adaddab66ef935d5644e3a663972

Comment: Code completion only triggers on certain keypresses. Can you give a specific example of when you would expect it to trigger but it doesn't? (Ideally a code snippet with info on which characters you typed when you expected it to appear)?

Comment: @DannyTuppeny Hi, danny, when I typed return new Container(child: ...) word 'child' cannot give auto completion without I pressed space bar first. normally when i started type c without pressed space, it should be appeared.

Comment: Hmm, that works for me. Can you open an issue [on GitHub](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code) and attach to it a [captured Analysis Server log](https://dartcode.org/docs/logging/#capture-logs-command) where you type that whole lone slowly (be sure type the whole of "new Container(child)").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you hit this issue:

https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/1374

It's fixed in the latest version of the Dart plugin. If you're still seeing it, please open a new issue on GitHub and I'll take a look. Thanks!